# Is there a way to compare two objects without comparing the attributes?

Tags: php, yii

I have two objects, in Yii framework we can do something like this:

```
$objectOne = Anything::model(); //and this is one object;
$objectTwo = Anything::model()->findByPk("1"); //and this is another object of the same class;
```

So now if I compare these two it will return 0, false, but what I want to compare are just the  instances of the objects, the class itself, not the attributes nor the values... I know that in Zend Framework we can do something similar by setting the parameters of a function to receive something like this:

```
public function anything ( Anything_Entity $something ){}
```

And by that things would work quite good, but I can't find any way to compare objects having the attributes to be ignored.

Comment: You may try to use [`instanceof`](http://php.net/instanceof) operator.

Comment: I'm glad to know people doesn't sleep like me, hahaha, thank you man, I'm gonna put it to work asap.

o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like CORRUPT commented, you can use [`instanceof`](http://php.net/instanceof). In Addition, you can also use [`get_class`](http://php.net/get-class)

```
// using instanceof
if ($obj1 instanceof SomeClass and $obj2 instanceof SomeClass) {
    // Do something
}

// using get_class
if (get_class($obj1) === get_class($obj2)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is couple of things worth mentioning here apart from the answer.

1. Type hinting is not a ZendFramework feature but a php feature. Typing hinting is what you have described as "I know that in Zend Framework we can do something similar by setting the parameters of a function to receive something like this:"

apart from that as CORRUPT mentioned you can use

```
if ($obj instanceof ClassName)
```

to see if a certain object is of a specific class

Comment: Understood. o>

Actually, I was thinking what PHP only had setted types for basic ones, wherever I got into (meaning PHP docs here) I only found information like that, I didn't get the proper question, I believe... or it wasn't so easy to find, well, anyways, thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Like @CORRUPT has mentioned in the comment, the best way to achieve this is by using  `instanceof`.  For example:

```
if ($objectOne instanceof Anything) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try that, but I believe this get_class thing it's pretty much what I was looking for, thank you. :)